# Fetch, set-cookies and csrf

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api

I m using Isomorphic fetch in my application and I m having some troubles dealing with CSRF.

Actually, I m having a backend that sends me a CSRF-TOKEN in set-cookies property :

[image]

I have read somewhere that it's not possible, or it's a bad practice to access this kind of cookies directly inside of my code.

This way, I tried to make something using the credentials property of fetch request :

```
const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
        });
        return this.fetcher(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers,
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: 'mail@mail.fr',
                password: 'password'
            })
        });
```

This way, I m able to send my CSRF cookie back to my server to serve my need (it's a different one, because it s not the same request) :

[image]

**My problem**

My problem is that my backend needs to receive a x-csrf-token header and so I can't set it to my POST request.

**What I need**

How can I do to put the value of *set-cookies: CSRF-TOKEN* into the next request *x-csrf-token* header ?

Answer (score 23):

It looks like in your scenario you are supposed to read from CSRF-TOKEN cookie. Otherwise it would be marked HttpOnly as JSESSIONID. The later means you cannot access it from the web page but merely send back to server automatically.

In general there is nothing wrong in reading CSRF token from cookies. Please check this good discussion: [Why is it common to put CSRF prevention tokens in cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504846/why-is-it-common-to-put-csrf-prevention-tokens-in-cookies)

You can read your cookie (not HttpOnly, of cause) using the following code

```
function getCookie(name) {
  if (!document.cookie) {
    return null;
  }

  const xsrfCookies = document.cookie.split(';')
    .map(c => c.trim())
    .filter(c => c.startsWith(name + '='));

  if (xsrfCookies.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return decodeURIComponent(xsrfCookies[0].split('=')[1]);
}
```

So fetch call could look like

```
const csrfToken = getCookie('CSRF-TOKEN');

const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
    });
    return this.fetcher(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: 'test@example.com',
            password: 'password'
        })
    });
```

Comment: Please fix the typo: X-XSRF-TOKEN should be X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: @Lunokhod, Header name depends on your server side and really can be either X-CSRF-TOKEN or X-XSRF-TOKEN or has some custom name

Answer (score 7):

Yes header name depends on your server. For example django usecase to setup CSRF token using fetch is like this:

```
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-CSRFToken': get_token
  },
```