# How do I configure JSData with cookie-based sessions and CSRF headers?

Tags: angular, csrf, jsdata

I need to set up my JSData configuration to pass along info for cookie-based session authentication, as well as CSRF headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating the `HttpAdapter`, use the following to set `withCredentials` ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)) and the CSRF header (example below sets the `X-CSRFToken` header, but that's specific to the server-side framework; it might be something else in others' cases).

```
const adapter = new HttpAdapter({
    ...
    httpConfig: {
        withCredentials: true // send cookie-based session credentials
    },
    ...
    beforeHTTP: function(config, opts) {
        ...
        config.headers || (config.headers = {});
        config.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = token;
        ...
        return HttpAdapter.prototype.beforeHTTP.call(this, config, opts);
    }
})
```

Getting the value for `token` can be done in different ways, e.g. [basic version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41721631/4185989), [Angular 2+ version](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18859#issuecomment-343386182), etc.