# How do you include a CSRF token in a Vue.js application with a Spring Boot backend?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to do a POST request to my backend REST API using the browser's Fetch API like this:

```
   submitRegistration() {
         const formElement = document.getElementById('register-form');
         fetch('http://localhost:8080/register', {
             method: 'POST',
             body: new FormData(formElement),
         });
     }
```

I'm taking the data from this form:

```
<v-form id="register-form" @submit.prevent="submitRegistration" class="text-center" ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
    <v-text-field type="text" name="username" v-model="form.username" :counter="25" :rules="usernameRules" label="Username" required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field type="password" name="userPassword" v-model="form.password" :counter="25" :rules="passwordRules" label="Password" required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field type="text" name="userEmail" v-model="form.email" :rules="emailRules" label="E-mail" required></v-text-field>
    <v-btn type="submit" text class="primary">Register</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

However, as a response I get **403 Forbidden** by my backend server. The problem is the CSRF token but I have no idea how to generate it to include it in the POST request to the backend API.

**EDIT**: In Spring Boot, my CORS mapping is configured like this:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000").allowCredentials(true);
        }
    };
}
```

I'm posting this because the `Response` object that is returned gives me a 403 status and is of type "cors" even though the error is resolved if I completely disable CSRF using HttpSecurity - `http.csrf().disable();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch, set-cookies and csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893537/fetch-set-cookies-and-csrf)

Comment: No, it didn't solve my problem. If I `console.log` the response of the POST request I get a response of type "cors" and a status 403. However, I have setup a mapping for the port my Vue.js app works on (9000) like this -> `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000").allowCredentials(true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be solved by making a `GET` call first to the server and then following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893537/fetch-set-cookies-and-csrf) with the following additions / corrections:

1. In the `submitRegistration()` method, add the following at the top:

   ```
       // Do a fetch to GET the XSRF-TOKEN as a cookie
       fetch('http://localhost:8080/register');
       const csrfToken = this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
       const headers = new Headers({
           'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
       });
   ```
2. Our POST request now looks like this:

   ```
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/register', {
           method: 'POST',
           headers,
           credentials: 'include',
           body: new FormData(formElement),
       })
   ```
3. In the backend, we need to add the following to our overriden `configure()` method:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
   }
   ```

   This tells the server to send back the CSRF token as a cookie called **"XSRF-TOKEN"** and reads the CSRF token from a header called **"X-XSRF-TOKEN"**.