# Django POST method is not working when using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, post

I am trying to display a div on submitting a form. It displays the div on submitting the form whereas form is not submitted. Here POST method is used. JavaScript is used to display the div.

html file:

```
                    <form method="POST" name="myFirstForm" id="chform">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="details_id" value="{{details.id}}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="details_user_id" value="{{details.user_id}}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{user.id}}"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="chat" onclick="return myFunction()" value="Chat Now">
                    </form>
                   <div class="page-content page-container" id="page-content" style="display:none"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
 document.forms['myFirstForm'].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
// Do something with the form's data here
this.style['display'] = 'none';
event.preventDefault();
  });
   function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("page-content");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

</script>
```

views.py:

```
    if request.method=='POST':
        jid = request.POST.get('details_id')
        print(jid)
        cjid = request.POST.get('details_user_id')
        print(cjid)
        userid = request.POST.get('user_id')
        print(userid)
```

If I not want to display the div and removes JavaScript code , POST method works.Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Asynchronous JavaScript And XML (AJAX)? It sounds to me like you want asynchronous JS functionality (or I'm not understanding correctly).

So in your submit button, you would make it call an AJAX function as follows:

```
<button type="submit" id="chat" data-url="{% url 'url_to_your_view_handling_the_post' %}" value="Chat Now"></button>
```

Then your `onclick` function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#chat', function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        data: {
            // add any other HTML data attributes in this dictionary
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
        },
        success: function (json_response) {
            // Successful AJAX response handling routine here
            // Display your div
            var x = document.getElementById("page-content");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) { }
    });
})
```

So your view at url `url_to_your_view_handling_the_post` defined in the button will handle the POST method and return a JSON response with whatever data you want. If it returns successfully, the success routine in your AJAX function is run.

Sending the csrf token is not extremely simple and I refer you to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893537/fetch-set-cookies-and-csrf) for more about the `getCookie('csrftoken')` function.

Note: This is a jquery implementation of AJAX therefore you’ll need to include jquery as well in your template.

Comment: This is using jQuery, so the author of the question will need to include that if they want to make an AJAX call with this function that you showed

Comment: Does $(this).data('url') represents data-url in biutton tag -@ Tine S Tsengwa

Comment: Yes. And the url is linked (by means of the urls.py) to the view that's handling the POST.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form, then you should not call `event.preventDefault();`. This basically tells js to capture the `submit` event and prevent the default behavior of the event which is to submit the form in your case.